# How to export to excel a version of a list at a specific date?

Tags: 2010

Is there a way to export to excel a version of a list at a specific date without development or with the small dev please ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a view with that date filter and click on "export to excel" button on the ribbon. Check it has the proper data.

Comment: I need the version of a list at a specific date. For example, I want the data in a list at the 10/03/2017. Of course i already activated the version history.

Comment: You mean you need to retrieve old versions of items filtered by date? There isn't anything by default in SharePoint that lets you recover all that information. You should implement some code in order to achieve this kind of requirement.